# How to set Django response status and error message and display it with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, django-rest-framework

### AngularJS throwing error message to user based on exactly what happens

My API built with Django Rest Framework.

There is only four field in my database.
they are, `userid, name, email, phone`

I write below this snippet and it's working fine to handle error and success:

```
$scope.formModel = {}; // It will post data and handle both success and error, 
  $scope.onSubmit = function () {
      $http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/contact/', $scope.formModel)
      .then(function(response){
        $scope.successPost = 'You have successfully submitted your Contact';
        $timeout(function(){
          $scope.successPost = '';
        },4000);
        $scope.contacts.push(response.data);
        
      }, function(response){
        $scope.errorPost = 'Ooops! It seems Your Submitted User ID or Phone Number or Email are already exist, please try again with different data';
        $timeout(function(){
          $scope.errorPost = '';
        },10000);
      });
      $scope.formModel = {};
      $scope.addContactForm.$setPristine();
  };
```

My back-end will not allow posting any duplicate item, like if a phone number exist in database, in 2nd time, user can't post this, if they try try to post a phone number that already exist, i want to show them a message that **"Your submitted phone number already exist"** Likewise, if he try to submit email that already exist, i want to show him a message like **"Your submitted email already exist"**

Currently my snippet works like if he can post successfully, he gets success message and if there is error, he get an error message but i want to show exactly what happened and why not accepted.

Comment: HTTP responses with status codes outside the range 200-299 go the the $http service rejection handler. The backend needs to set the status code and message appropriately.

Answer (score -1):

I would look at the specific error that is being returned in the response, then based on that message I would display the appropriate message.  If the server is not returning different messages, I would correct that issue first.  If you can't you may need to implement more client side logic such as seeing if any of the values exist before the user fills out the form and make them read only or similar.

```
function(response){
    //could use case statements too instead of if statements.
    if(response.cantRememberVarName == "user id already exists"){
      $scope.errorPost = "Ooops User Id already exists";
    }
    if(response.cantRemberVarName == "phone number already exists"){
      ....
    }
    $scope.errorPost = 'Ooops! It seems Your Submitted User ID or Phone Number or Email are already exist, please try again with different data';
    $timeout(function(){
      $scope.errorPost = '';
    },10000);
  });
```

Comment: The response object from the $http service does not have a property named `cantRememberVarName`. For more information, see [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - returns](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-returns).